# How can I mock a single method from a mocked class in jest?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using `node 12` and jest for unit testing. I have a code to open connection via websocket.

```
      const ws = require('ws');
      this.ws = new WebSocket(url);
      this.ws.on('open', () => {
        // How to test this callback?
        ...
        resolve();
      });
      this.ws.on('error', (err) => {
        // How to test this callback?
        ...
        reject(err)
      });
```

In my test case, I have mocked `ws` module via jtest:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

jest.mock('ws')

test('quote server listener should be able to connect to quote server', () => {
  const server = new QuoteServerListener(null, 'http://mock.com');
  server.connect();
  const mockWSInstance = WebSocket.mock.instances[0];
  expect(mockWSInstance.on).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

The above test case works fine. But I don't know how to trigger a call to the callback function on `ws.on('open', () => ...`. I'd like to test the logic when the connection is open. How can I achieve this in the mock? 
I have tried to emit a `open` event via `mockWSInstance` instance like `mockWSInstance.emit('open', null)` but it doesn't trigger the code. What should I do in this case?

Comment: I suggest instead of having inline anonymous function you can have named function and pass it in the "on" event. The named function you can mock. e.g. function onOpen() { } ws.on("open", onOpen). Now you can mock or spyOn onOpen.

Comment: I have to pass some parameters to these methods like `resolve` `reject` which doesn't looks nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution:
`index.ts`:

```js
export class SomeClass {
  ws;
  run() {
    const WebSocket = require("ws");
    const url = "";
    this.ws = new WebSocket(url);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.ws.on("open", () => {
        resolve();
      });
      this.ws.on("error", err => {
        reject(err);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { SomeClass } from "./";
const WebSocket = require("ws");

jest.mock("ws", () => {
  const mWebSocket = {
    on: jest.fn()
  };
  return jest.fn(() => mWebSocket);
});

describe("SomeClass", () => {
  let instance;
  let ws;
  beforeEach(() => {
    ws = new WebSocket();
    instance = new SomeClass();
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it("should pass", async () => {
    const eventHandler = {};
    ws.on.mockImplementation((event, handler) => {
      eventHandler[event] = handler;
    });
    const pending = instance.run();
    eventHandler["open"]();
    const actual = await pending;
    expect(actual).toBeUndefined();
    expect(ws.on).toBeCalledWith("open", eventHandler["open"]);
  });

  it("should fail", async () => {
    const eventHandler = {};
    ws.on.mockImplementation((event, handler) => {
      eventHandler[event] = handler;
    });
    const pending = instance.run();
    const mError = new Error("connection error");
    eventHandler["error"](mError);
    await expect(pending).rejects.toThrowError(mError);
    expect(ws.on).toBeCalledWith("error", eventHandler["error"]);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59084313/index.spec.ts
  SomeClass
    ✓ should pass (4ms)
    ✓ should fail (3ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.781s, estimated 8s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59084313